# Javascript/Coffeescript Using Hash of Functions As Argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have some Coffeescript that looks like this (apologies for the complexity in advance):

```
doc = new ChargerServerDoc(Chargers.find({id:site.id}), site)

doc.set_defaults().merge().needs_update
  update: (id, doc) ->
    Chargers.update id, $set: doc, (error, result) ->
      if error
        run_stats.error_count += 1
        "error"
      else
        run_stats.update_count += 1
        "update"

    return

  insert: (doc) ->
    Chargers.insert doc, (error, result) ->
      if error
        run_stats.error_count += 1
        "error"
      else
        run_stats.insert_count += 1
        "insert"

    return
```

It's supposed to create some sort of document and implement insert or update to the database as callbacks.

```
needs_update: (callbacks = null) ->

  console.log inspect arguments

  if callbacks is null
    return true unless @is_equal(@working_document, @retrieved_document)
    return false
  else
    console.log """
    callbacks not null:
    insert: #{inspect callbacks['insert']}
    update: #{inspect callbacks['update']} 
    """
    data = @get()
    if @is_equal(@working_document, @retrieved_document)
      throw 'requires update callback' if _.isEmpty(callbacks.update)
      return callbacks.update.call(this, data._id, _.omit(data, '_id'))
    else
      throw 'require insert callback' if _.isEmpty(callbacks.insert)
      return callbacks.insert.call(this, _.omit(data, '_id'))
```

As you can see, the `needs_update` function is peppered with `console.log` statements. This is running in node.js, and it's a run-once-at-startup thing. So it's not easy to watch in the node inspector. At least I haven't figured out how.

In any case, the interesting part of this is the `console.log inspect arguments`. `inspect` just converts the object to a JSON string so I can read it. And the result is always `{"0":{}}`.

And that's where I'm stuck. I can see it's passing a hash, but there's nothing in the hash. Stranger still, this same behavior occurs when I hand write it in pure Javascript.

I tried to reduce this and reproduce it to no avail. This code works:

```
h =
  f1: (a) -> 'one'
  f2: (b) -> 'two'

test = (fn) ->
  console.log fn.f1.call()
  console.log fn.f2.call()

test(h)
```

Does anyone see why the first code fails and the reduced example works?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It calls JSON.stringify() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: @muistooshort-- the `console.log` that starts with `callbacks not null` does very much what you say: It examines the two key/value pairs I expect and they both come up `undefined`. I've tried to simplify it, but at the core, I don't understand why the arguments are turning up with an empty hash.

Comment: It turns out the code is fine. The thing that was going wrong was that `throw 'requires update callback' if _.isEmpty(callbacks.update)` and the same for insert were firing even though the callbacks were being provided. For some reason, the provided functions evaluated as empty by Underscore. Removing the lines that threw the exceptions solved the problem. So I'll reframe the question: Why would these tests for absence of a callback evaluate to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not use `_.isEmpty` correctly. From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty):

> **isEmpty** `_.isEmpty(object)`
>
> Returns *true* if an enumerable **object** contains no values (no enumerable own-properties). For strings and array-like objects `_.isEmpty` checks if the length property is 0.

A function is not an enumerable object, nor is it a string or array-like object. You're giving `_.isEmpty` something that it doesn't understand so you're invoking unspecified behavior. Turns out that `_.isEmpty` returns `true` for anything it doesn't understand.

If you want to see if something is a function, [`_.isFunction`](http://underscorejs.org/#isFunction) would probably serve you better:

```
throw 'requires update callback' unless _.isFunction(callbacks.update)
```

Comment: I was checking whether the argument was supplied rather than whether it was a function. You're probably right that checking that it's a function makes sense but I'm not sure `isEmpty` is really being used wrong. Looking at the code on Github, the comments and the code tell me that if you pass null, you get true. Here: `if (obj == null) return true;`. (https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1168) So while the comment does not explicitly reference `null` as a possible "empty" value, the code does. I believe this is how almost all empty or blank functions work.

Comment: Accepted as the correct answer because the test really *should* be for whether a callback function is supplied.

Comment: Yes, the code considers `null` (and `undefined`, hence the `== null` instead of `=== null`) as "empty" but it is still expecting certain types of non-null inputs.